# Cannot read property push of undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte modelo:

`produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.model.ts`:

```
export class ProdutosConfirmadosAnuncio{

   idContasAnunciarB2W:[{id: number}];

}
```

Inicializo ele desta forma:

```
produtosConfirmadosAnuncio: ProdutosConfirmadosAnuncio[] = []
```

Em um determinado momento da minha aplicação eu devo adicionar um objeto nesse `Array`:

```
if(this.contasB2W[i] == event.option.viewValue){
   console.log(this.idContasB2W[i])
   this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[index].idContasAnunciarB2W.push({id: this.idContasB2W[i]});
}
```

E então recebo na linha que contém o `push`:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Nesse `console.log` é impresso o valor 22.

Comment: A variável **index** existe?

Comment: Sim, eu já descobri o problema, vou adicionar uma resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi dessa forma:

Fiz uma lógica para só dar push se tiver elementos, se não tiver elementos ainda recebe dessa forma o objeto:

```
this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[index].idContasAnunciarB2W = [{id: this.idContasB2W[i]}];
```

E então, os próximos pushs que vierem funcionaram normalmente.